# Ask someone 'about' something or ask someone 'for' something?

Tags: prepositions

When A wants to know the telephone number of B, do we say:

> A wants to ask B about B's cellphone number

or:

> A wants to ask B for B's cellphone number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking **about** something refers to a topic, for example, you would ask a coworker *about* their weekend.  You can't actually get someone's weekend activities, as it is not an object, but you can learn more about what they did, where they went, etc.

Asking **for** something refers to an actual object, for example, you would ask *for* a hamburger at a fast food restaurant.  You can ask *about* a hamburger, but you would be asking about the details of it, like the ingredients, if it is organic, etc.

---

For your specific sentence, I would use **for** instead of about.  You are asking for an object that you will be using, not details about the number.